# Ubuntu 16.04 WIFI not working after install

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have tried installing 'additional drivers' and going through several of the posts on the forum looking for a solution.  However, I cannot figure it out.

Can someone please help me get my wifi working?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0623]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

And then

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1600000-d1607fff memory:d1400000-d15fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:76:1c:5b:c8:2d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.90 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1804000-d1804fff memory:d1800000-d1803fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing secure boot to disabled.